# Get specific range of dates when flood value is low in GEE Sentinel-1

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, datetime, flood

I am new at GEE and I am trying to do some flood analysis, I already have a time series of flood for one point, I did it getting the value from VV band of sentinel-1. Now I want to get the range of dates when the point is "dry", for example for this case would be between 2017-10-12 and 2018-01-06:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to find an automatic way to get this range and to store it in variables as:

```
first_date:'2017-10-12'
second date: '2018-01-06'
```

I have tried a lot of ways (filtering the image collection with:

```
var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.lt('VV', 24));
```

But filtered object results empty, I also tried to create a list with date and value and filter it with values below 24 but GEE collapses and close!!!

Someone know what can I do?

This is mi code:

```
var geometry= ee.Geometry.Point([-60.29159,-3.38608])
var startDate = '2017-05-01'
var endDate = '2018-05-28'

// function to convert to dB scale
function convert2dB(collection) {
  var dBCollection = collection.map(function(image) {
  var processedImage = image.expression('10 * log10(i * i) - 83', {
      i: image.select('HH')
    });
    return image.addBands(processedImage.rename('HH_dB'));
  });
  return dBCollection;
}



//Cargamos SENTINEL

var S1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate(startDate,endDate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))


function makeMosaics_S1(image) {
  var thisImage = ee.Image(image);
  var date = ee.Date(thisImage.get('system:time_start'));
  // add only hour to exclude images from other paths
  var filteredDataset = S1.filterDate(date, date.advance(1,'hour'));
  // add all image properties to the new image
  var toReturn = ee.Image(filteredDataset.mosaic()
                    .copyProperties(image,image.propertyNames())
                    );
  // add geometries
  var geometries = filteredDataset.map(function(img){
    return ee.Feature(img.geometry());
  });
  
  var mergedGeometries = geometries.union();
  return toReturn.set('system:footprint', mergedGeometries.geometry());
}

// the final collection without duplicates

var mosaiced_S1 = S1.map(makeMosaics_S1);
var post_filtered_S1 = mosaiced_S1.filter(ee.Filter.contains('.geo', geometry));

//Classify water SENTINEL
var classifyWater_VV = function(img) {
  var vv = img.select('VV_Filtered').abs().rename('Water_S1')
   return img.addBands(vv)//Return image with added classified water band
}

mosaiced_S1=mosaiced_S1.map(classifyWater_VV)
print('classify Sentinel-1', mosaiced_S1)

var ClassChart_S1 = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: mosaiced_S1.select('Water_S1'),
  region: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  scale: 150,
})
  .setOptions({
      title: 'Inundated Pixels',
      hAxis: {'title': 'Date'},
      vAxis: {'title': 'Flood'},
      lineWidth: 2
    })
  
print(ClassChart_S1)
```

Comment: https://google-earth-engine.com/Aquatic-and-Hydrological-Applications/Surface-Water-Mapping/